# Article (Elsevier) option twocolumn ineffective (Lyx)

Tags: lyx, two-column, elsarticle

In Lyx I want to create a two column article with `elsarticle` (a class document offered by lyx).

I want to add the class options `3p, times, twocolumn` (I add them in the `textbox` options of document class in the settings section) but it is not effective in the generated document. It only creates one column.

What settings am I missing?

Here's the code in code tex:

```
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{Title} \author{So Nia} \address{Department, University} \ead{so.nia@somewhere.xyz}
\begin{abstract} \end{abstract}
\end{frontmatter}
\section{Start}
```

Comment: You might get more help if you post a minimal example .tex file exported from LyX. For more information, see https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample.

Comment: its a configuration no code written yet, i want to know how to configure Lyx for a twocolumn elsarticle

Comment: @scottkosty please check my EDIT

Comment: The title and the abstract will occupy both columns in a twocolumn document. Did you already try to add some actual text after the section title? Is this text displayed in two columns?

Comment: Yes i did try to add text, it goes on way beyond the doc border with no line breaks and without considering twocolumn option, so no twocolumn display with the example shown

Comment: @joe thanks. I don't think I'll know how to solve it, but hopefully someone else will. Note that you should post a complete working example, not just one chunk.

Comment: @scottkosty it's super easy to set this normally for you guys tex experienced. In lyx i write code in a tex code window, i added to code i use as tex code

Comment: By "textbox", do you mean the one where it says "Custom", as I did in this screenshot?https://i.stack.imgur.com/ka2kN.png  With the settings shown there (no other changes made), any text after `\end{frontmatter}` is set in two columns.

Comment: Still doesn't work but thanks @Torbjørn for your endeavors